# How to define a dynamic attribute for a many to many relationship in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, many-to-many, accessor

I have a many-to-many relationship from `Order`s to `Product`s, as follows:

```
class Order extends Model {
    ...
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')
                    ->withPivot('unit_price', 'quantity');
    }
}
```

I can access the attributes of the relationship using `$order->pivot->unit_price` and `$order->pivot->quantity`.

But is there a way I can create accessors to this relationship?
For instance, `$order->pivot->subTotal` would return `unit_price * quantity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, what you are looking for is the `Pivot` class, it is easy to implement, here's a [tutorial](http://softonsofa.com/laravel-custom-pivot-model-in-eloquent/) for you.